# Scrambling records within a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently preparing some Test data and require anonymizing of the original records. So I would like to scramble records within a column without affecting other columns in thesame Row.

Mr Adam in Row 1 will be Mr Adam in Row 4....other details about Mr Adam are to be retained in Row 1.

Below is an example

Table name: `dept`

```
     Title  Firstname    Lastname      Telephone    other columns...
1    Mr     Adam             Smith         001   
2    Mrs    Angela           Evans         002  
3    Mr     Bill             Towny         003 
4    Miss   Dame             Beaut         004
```

I am interested in transforming it as per below

```
     Title  Firstname    Lastname      Telephone    other columns...
1    Miss   Dame             Smith         001   
2    Mr     Bill             Evans         002  
3    Mrs    Angela           Towny         003 
4    Mr     Adam             Beaut         004
```

You will notice ONLY the firstname and associated title has been scrambled...other fields such as lastname and telephone remain the same...

Below is my attempt...I couldn't get the Title to be scrambled along with the firstname

```
SELECT
  FirstName as TempFirstNamecolumn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) As Rowno
Into #TempFirstNametable
FROM dept


alter table dept
add Row int identity(1,1)

UPDATE dept
SET FirstName = #TempFirstNametable.TempFirstNamecolumn
FROM #VirtualFirstNametable WHERE Row= Rowno 

alter table dept
DROP COLUMN Row

DROP TABLE #TempFirstNametable
```

Comment: no, its not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update  t1
set t1.title=b.title,
    t1.firstname=b.firstname
from dept t1
cross apply
(select  top 1  t2.title,t2.firstname
from 
dept t2
where
t1.title<>t2.title and t1.firstname<>t2.firstname
order by newid()
)b
```

Comment: For further information see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-rand-function.htm

Comment: Is t1 a temp or main table?  Based on your script, I am getting an error that 'it could not be bound' ...        update dept
                      set dept.Title=b.title,
    dept.Firstname=b.firstname
from #temp dept
cross apply
(select  top 1  t2.title,t2.Firstname
from 
#temp t2
where
dept.title<>t2.title and dept.firstname<>t2.firstname
order by rand()
)b

Comment: @optimisteve: Replace temp with your main table

Comment: didn't work. what could I be doing wrongly. Here is the change.   update dept set dept.Title=b.title, dept.Firstname=b.firstname from #dept dept cross apply (select top 1 t2.title,t2.Firstname from #dept t2 where dept.title<>t2.title and dept.firstname<>t2.firstname order by rand() )b

Comment: what didn't work.Can you elaborate,it shuffles firstname and title ,other than which are already present

Comment: Error I am getting is 'Invalid column name title' for the b.title. It appears your 'b' is a temporary table. Cant seem to see any line in the script on how you created 'b' table. Also when you say 'replace temp with main table' is this what you mean..to change from from #temp t1 to from #dept t1?  or do you mean anywhere in the script where there is t1, I should replace with dept? Many thanks

Comment: @optimisteve:Assuming Dept is your table,i have updated the code,try this

Comment: @TheGameiswar, thanks a lot for your time. It seem to have shuffled, how do I UPDATE ALL the records accordingly?.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, I think your script only has 'select  top 1'. How do I do the same for all the records...I tried select * already

Comment: That is correlated subquery

Comment: @TheGameiswar my apologies if my questions are so basic and appear dumb. Only just getting a hang on this thing. All I want to do is apply the script for all the records. I am lost on how to go about that. I have about 600 records within the dept table that require the transformation. So I replaced the 'select  top 1' with 'select  top 600'...From what I can see, All the records in the firstname have been replaced by just only 2 first names randomly. ie All the 600 firstname column either has Adam or Dame.

Comment: don't replace top 1 or any thing,the above code will work as it is

Comment: thanks again and as always. I did exactly that...using the script (select top 1). The records in the first name column did change but issue here is all the names in the 600 have been replaced with either of 2 first names ie you will find only either Adam or Dame in all columns. I can only see 2 first names scattered randomly. This is giving serious headache...lol.

Comment: Can you provide total data for me to test

Comment: You can create data here and provide me the link:http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @TheGameiswar you are the CHAMP!!! thanks so much, works like charm and half of my problem has been solved by you. If I want the Gender moved along with the title and the firstname, would this be ok......as per this script  
update  t1
    set t1.title=b.title,
        t1.firstname=b.firstname
        t1.gender=b.gender
    from dept t1
    cross apply
    (select  top 1  t2.title,t2.firstname,t2.gender
    from 
    dept t2
    where
    t1.title<>t2.title and t1.firstname<>t2.firstname<>t2.gender
    order by newid()
    )b ...getting invalid column name error for 'b.gender'

Comment: Thank you so much sir...made my day!

Comment: what is the 'select top 1' actually doing in the statement..is it selecting the first record only...that's the only grey area for me in the script   also, for the addition of the associated gender, I used where t1.title<>t2.title and t1.firstname<>t2.firstname order by newid() )b INSTEAD of where t1.title<>t2.title and t1.firstname<>t2.firstname<>t2.gender order by newid() )b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123174/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-optimisteve).

Comment: @TheGameiswar. Thanks for yesterday. I think I used the script blindly without understanding the logic behind it. What I need to clarify 1. update t1...couldn't that have been replaced with the table name so it is 'update dept'..so whats the difference between using t1 and dept? 2. Whats the use of 'select top 1' in the query..why not 'select *' or 'select top 600' or something. 3. the b outside the last bracket. Lastly, ending part of the script ; whats the essence of using the query for 'if firstname in t1 is not the same as firstname in t2'? Apologies for the seemingly 'stupid' questions

Comment: please ask a new question with all the details,you could also look here to improve the question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I would just join the randomised fields...

```
with TIT as 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) As Rowno,
        Title
 from dept
)

, FORE as
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) As Rowno,
        Firstname
 from dept
)
, SUR as
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) As Rowno,
        Lastname
 from dept
)
,PHONE as
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) As Rowno,
        Telephone
 from dept
)

select Title, Firstname, Surname, Telephone
from TIT
inner join FORE
 on TIT.rowno = Fore.Rowno
inner join SUR 
 on TIT.rowno = SUR.Rowno
inner join PHONE
 on TIT.rowno = PHONE.Rowno
...
```

Comment: RAND function randomizes ROWs that is moves 1 full row to another row, what I want to randomise is particular records in a row to another row while keeping other associated information of the record in the original row position. Mr John in Row 1 will be Mr John in Row 5....other details about Mr John are to be retained in Row 1.